# Suggestion for references

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

Can anyone suggest me some good references for studying HENON MAPS. I have no information about these maps at all. So please suggest some references for going through its basics.

Comment: Did you mean the [*Henon Map*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HenonMap.html) from dynamical systems? If so, see the nice list of references at the link. If so, I can recommend several more wonderful books, but you can find more on the web and on Wiki. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti yes the henon map from dynamical system, please suggest me some books as well. and thanks for the references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Books**

Gleick, J. Chaos: Making a New Science. New York: Penguin Books, pp. 144-153, 1988.

[*Chaos and Fractals, by David Feldman*](http://books.google.com/books?id=exnWM_ZHK0MC&pg=PA275&dq=H%C3%A9non&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SpoOUc68CrHAiwKAm4H4Aw&ved=0CEIQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=H%C3%A9non&f=false)

Dynamical Systems with Applications Using Mathematica By Stephen Lynch

A First Course in Chaotic Dynamical Systems, by Robert L. Devaney

Nonlinear Dynamics And Chaos: With Applications To Physics, Biology, Chemistry And Engineering (Studies in Nonlinearity), Steven H. Strogatz

Dynamics and Bifurcations, Jack K. Hale (Author), Huseyin Kocak

**Papers**

[*Complete Bifurcation Behaviors of a Henon Map by Albert C. J. Luo, Yu Guo*](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-5754-2_5)

[*Dynamical Behavior of Two Dimensional Hénon Maps by MS Islam*](http://www.banglajol.info/index.php/BJSIR/article/view/10722)

Many other online sources (Google them)

**Mathematica CDF (Free)**

[*Orbit Diagram of the Hénon Map*](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/OrbitDiagramOfTheHenonMap//)

**Software**

[*Phaser*](http://www.phaser.com/)

Regards

Comment: @Azmoti thanks alot for such a descriptive reference. thanks alot, it,ll be really helpful for me.

Comment: You are very welcome! Enjoy the explorations! Regards

Comment: Accepted, and $0$ thumbs up??? Not any more...hope more are forthcoming!